# How to return from a function

Tags: common-lisp

I have a function like this.

```
(defun foo ()
  (if (condition)
     (do-something)))
```

But I want to write like this to avoid unnecessary indent.

```
(defun foo ()
  (if not (condition) (return))
  (do-something))
```

Obviously `return` isn't caught because there is no block here.

How can I get out of the function?
Or is this a bad way with lisp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defun creates a block named for the function name, which can be used by calling return-from.

```
(return-from foo (do-something))
```

It's not good style to use this to avoid a little indentation. Your editor should be able to do indentation automatically, and functions are usually easier to read without early returns.

Comment: I'd argue that "good style" isn't the main issue. That's too subjective in a short answer. Maybe what you mean by style is: since, in that case, the function returns automatically without having to call `return-from` explicitly, it's a better choice because it would make the code more concise.

Answer (score 1):

@m-n already answered your question fully. I just want to provide an example of what 'good style' would be in this case:

```
(defun foo ()
  (when (condition)
    (do-something)))
```

In my opinion, it even does look better than

```
(defun foo ()
  (if (condition)
      (do-something)))
```

and in particular than

```
(defun foo ()
  (if (not (condition)) (return-from foo))
  (do-something))
```

(This is the indentation as my emacs with slime etc. produces it)

N.B.: Instead of `(when (not (condition)) ...)` use `(unless (condition) ...)`.

Comment: Can I ask why `when` is better than `if` in this case?

Comment: `when` never has an else clause, thus using `when` makes ones intention clear that there is no 'else'. From a performance percpective it does not matter. `when` is a macro that expands to `(if (condition) (do-something) nil)` on at least SBCL. I don't know what the standard says.